# Neural networks and Python

Tags: java, python, arrays, zip

I'm trying to study about neural networks, following a great guide:
http://neuralnetworksanddeeplearning.com/chap1.html

Currently I've reached this code snippet which I'm trying to understand and write in Java:

```
class Network(object):

def __init__(self, sizes):
    self.num_layers = len(sizes)
    self.sizes = sizes
    self.biases = [np.random.randn(y, 1) for y in sizes[1:]]
    self.weights = [np.random.randn(y, x) 
                    for x, y in zip(sizes[:-1], sizes[1:])]
```

I managed to figure out what everything means except for the last line:
`[np.random.randn(y, x) for x, y in zip(sizes[:-1], sizes[1:])]`

As far as I can understand: create a matrix with y rows and x columns, for each pair x,y which can be found in the matrix `zip` which is created by the merging of the two "sizes" arrays. I understand that `sizes[1:]` means taking all elements from sizes starting from index 1, but `sizes[:-1]` makes no sense to me.

I read online that `s[::-1]` means getting the reverse of the array, but in the above case we only have one colon, while in the formula for the reverse array there seems to be two colons.

Sadly, I have no idea how Python works and I got pretty far along with the online book to give it up now (I also truly like it), so can someone say if I'm right until now, correct me if needed, or straight out explaining that final line?

Comment: Does `sizes[:-1]` by any chance mean: take the array in reverse, but skip the last element? I'm trying to deduce it through writing examples and this seems to make sense.

Comment: No, that is a list slice which returns the same list without the last item.

Comment: Oh! So for sizes = [1,2,3], then sizes[:-1] = [1,2]?

Comment: Yep, that's right. Open up your python interpreter and play around.

Comment: Thank you very much Nasef! Could you please post this as an answer to the question rather than a comment to it so that I can upvote your answer and choose it as the solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`sizes[:-1]` is a list slice which returns a copy of the `sizes` list but without the last item.

Comment: Thank you for your time and concise answer Nasef! Have a great day.

Comment: No problem, glad I could help.